# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Fractional Scaling not Working (Intel GPU)

Tags: 20.04

There are similar issues for Nvidia-based GPUs.  However, I am using Intel GPU based on the `i915` driver I believe.

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

When I enable Fractional Scaling in Display, the screen refreshes but continues to only show 100% and 200% options.

I've logged in with both Wayland and X11 sessions.  I've also rebooted.

[image: fractional scaling ubuntu 20.04 not working]

EDIT: A few final notes...

- I have also tried running the `gsettings` commands for both X11 and Wayland, to no avail.
- Gnome `gsettings` works fine on Ubuntu 18.10, 19.04, and 19.10 fresh installs, running the latest custom Surface kernel (5.6.x).
- This is a new 20.04 ISO install - not an upgrade.
- I am running the latest Linux kernel using a special build for Surface, which is newer than the one that ships and is available with 20.04.  Note again: this same kernel works fine with 19.10 and fractional scaling forced via gsettings under X11.

```
$ uname -a
Linux surface3 5.6.7-surface #2 SMP Sun May 3 15:07:53 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Changing kernels back to the stock 20.04 LTS one is not an option on this device, as nothing will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.  The `gsettings` must have been messing with the GUI.

Once I cleared the `gsettings`, rebooted, I had the scaling options.

TL/DR: Don't use `gsettings` to change the fractional scaling on Ubuntu 20.04.